# How to modify OnMapReadyCallback (declared in MapsFragment) at MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning how to deal with MapsFragment in Kotlin. So I am considering an example app consists of the followings:

- MainActivity = having one button and one frameLayout
- MapsFragment.

As you may guess, the MapsFragment is set to the frameLayout in MainActivity by the following way (this is a part of code in my `MainActivity.kt`):

```
var mapsFragment: MapsFragment
mapsFragment = MapsFragment()
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, mapsFragment)
transaction.commit()
```

Now, what I am trying to implement as an exercise is the following: when one clicks the button, then a new marker appears in the (google) map at the current location. For this purpose, I implement a function getting the current location information called `getLastKnownLocation(context: Context)`.

As it is explained in the automatically created comment in the `MapsFragment.kt` file, markers are added to the map by using `private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback`, which is declared in `MapsFragment.kt`. But, for me, it seems like that there is no way to modify the variable `callback` in `MainActivity.kt`. I am not sure if this is the correct design of mechanism, but as a newcomer in this field, I naively guessed that I am required to implement the following procedure (1) button click, (2) get the current location, (3) location is delivered to `callback`, (4) new marker appears for my purpose. But I could not figure out how to achieve the steps (3) and (4).

Could anyone give any tips for my (self) exercise? If there is better way to implement my exercise program through a procedure other than my naively guessed procedure, it would also be greatly helpful.

---

[Added] I should clarify what I want a bit more. Let us say that there are already N number of makers in the map. I want to add one more marker by clicking the button (previous N markers are still there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered very clearly [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#None-kotlin), you need to modify your `Activity` to implement the `OnMapReadyCallback` `interface`, this will require you to `override` `onMapReady` function, which you can do as following

```
// Declare a property in your class to keep a reference to map object
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

// This will be called when your map is ready
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
        .position(sydney)
        .title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

Now simply register this `callback` on your map `fragment`

```
val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

### As to how to get last known location and set it on map

```
// Declare a propery to keep a reference to FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

// In your Activity onCreate method do fusedLocationClient init as
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

// Then register a callback to receive last known location, call it in the end of onMapReady
private fun getLastLocation(){
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            location?.let{
             val currentLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.latitude)
             mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                 .position(currentLocation )
                 .title("Me"))
            }
        }
 }
```

Since you want to set the location on map, only call `getLastLocation` function in the end of `onMapReady` function(so that map is ready, when we try to set a marker)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that I have to add one more which I really want to know but I forgot to write in the main body of the question. What I really want to implement is add new maker with keeping previously added makers. Do you think that it is just an application of the method you explained?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment at @mightyWOZ's answer, you wanted to apply previously marker. You can achieve this by storing the first location inside a[SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Refer to @mightyWOZ's answer, you can add the `SharedPreference` inside it.

```
private fun getLastLocation(){
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            location?.let{
             val currentLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.latitude)
             mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                 .position(currentLocation )
                 .title("Me"))
            storeLastLocation(currentLocation)
            }
        }
 }
```

Here is the method we want to save and call the location which is stored in the `SharedPreference`. In this example, I'm using [FastSave](https://github.com/yehiahd/FastSave-Android) as the `SharedPreference`.

```
private fun storeLastLocation(latLng: LatLng){
   //Initialize the list
   var listLocation : MutableList<LatLng> = mutableListOf()
   //Check if the key exist or not
   if(FastSave.getInstance().isKeyExist(Constant.LOCATION)){
      //if yes, store them inside the list
      listLocation = FastSave.getInstance().getObjectList(Constant.LOCATION, LatLng::java.class)
    }
    //We store new location
    listLocation.add(latLng)
    FastSave.getInstance().saveObjectList(Constant.LOCATION, listLocation)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that the system does not allow to take both @mightyWOZ's and your's as for the answer to this question...

Comment: @User0829 he answered it first. I did some improvement only