# Using Markers in Xamarin.Android Application

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android for the application I am building.

I am creating an application that should have 5 buttons on the `activity_main.xml` and when each of those buttons are clicked, I want them to open a map pointing to different locations, but I seem not to be able to achieve this objective. The good part is I am able to render my maps on all activities, but I am not able to add markers.
The follwing are some of the code snipets that might help you help me out and I am using the TaxCollectionActivity as an example of what I am trying to achieve:

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

namespace KabweUtilityApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            
            // Get references to the buttons
            Button btnGarbageCollection = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGarbageCollection);
            Button btnWaterBillService = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnWaterBillService);
            Button btnElectricityBillService = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnElectricityBillService);
            Button btnTVBillService = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTVBillService);
            Button btnTaxCollection = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTaxCollection);

            // Handle button clicks
            btnGarbageCollection.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                btnGarbageCollection.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    double latitude = -14.447184; // Replace with the actual latitude value for ZRA Kabwe office
                    double longitude = 28.446448; // Replace with the actual longitude value for ZRA Kabwe office

                    var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(GarbageCollectionActivity));
                    intent.PutExtra("latitude", latitude);
                    intent.PutExtra("longitude", longitude);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                };
            };

            btnWaterBillService.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                double latitude = -14.447184; // Replace with the actual latitude value for ZRA Kabwe office
                double longitude = 28.446448; // Replace with the actual longitude value for ZRA Kabwe office

                var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(WaterBillServiceActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("latitude", latitude);
                intent.PutExtra("longitude", longitude);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };

            btnElectricityBillService.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Pass relevant data for ElectricityBillServiceActivity
                string customerId = "123456"; // Replace with the actual customer ID
                int unitsConsumed = 50; // Replace with the actual units consumed

                var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(ElectricityBillServiceActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("customerId", customerId);
                intent.PutExtra("unitsConsumed", unitsConsumed);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };

            btnTVBillService.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Pass relevant data for TVBillServiceActivity
                double latitude = -14.447184; // Replace with the actual latitude value for ZRA Kabwe office
                double longitude = 28.446448; // Replace with the actual longitude value for ZRA Kabwe office

                var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(TVBillServiceActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("latitude", latitude);
                intent.PutExtra("longitude", longitude);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };

            btnTaxCollection.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                double latitude = -14.447184; // Replace with the actual latitude value for ZRA Kabwe office
                double longitude = 28.446448; // Replace with the actual longitude value for ZRA Kabwe office

                var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(TaxCollectionActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("latitude", latitude);
                intent.PutExtra("longitude", longitude);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }

        
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGarbageCollection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Garbage Collection" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWaterBillService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Water Bill Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnElectricityBillService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Electricity Bill Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTVBillService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TV Bill Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaxCollection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tax Collection" />

    

</GridLayout>
```

MapFragment.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using KabweUtilityApp;

namespace KabweUtilityApp
{
    public class MapFragment : Android.Gms.Maps.MapFragment, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap map;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            SetUpMap();

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_map, container, false);
            return view;
        }

        private void SetUpMap()
        {
            if (map == null)
            {
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.mapContainer).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            GetMapAsync(this);
        }

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            this.map = googleMap;
            // Customize the map as needed
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(13.0291), Convert.ToDouble(80.2083));
            CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);
            map.MoveCamera(camera);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(latlng).SetTitle("Chennai");
            map.AddMarker(options);
        }

    }
}
```

TaxCollection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Add your UI elements for the Electricity Bill Service page here -->

<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TaxCollection.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Java.Util;

namespace KabweUtilityApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Tax Collection", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.TaxCollection")]
    public class TaxCollectionActivity : AppCompatActivity, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap map;
        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            this.map = googleMap;
        }

        

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.tax_collection);


            double latitude = Intent.GetDoubleExtra("latitude", -14.447184);
            double longitude = Intent.GetDoubleExtra("longitude", 28.446448);
            // Add any additional logic or functionality specific to the Tax Collection page
        }
    }
    
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        

        
        
        
        <activity
    android:name=".GarbageCollectionActivity"
    android:label="Garbage Collection"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.GarbageCollection"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCPSp7Hvfz8FQa3bc--wCh8vr_yp_6-kwk" />

        
        
        <activity
    android:name=".WaterBillServiceActivity"
    android:label="Water Bill Service"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WaterBillService" />

        <activity
    android:name=".ElectricityBillServiceActivity"
    android:label="Electricity Bill Service"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ElectricityBillService" />

        <activity
    android:name=".TVBillServiceActivity"
    android:label="TV Bill Service"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TVBillService" />

        <activity
    android:name=".TaxCollectionActivity"
    android:label="Tax Collection"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TaxCollection" />




    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    
    
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>
```

I am able to provide any other code snippets that would be necessay.

[image: My MainActivity]

[image: My Tax Collection Activity]

I have tried to use markers as guided in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api) but nothing happens, the map remains as it is in the example given above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, did you request the location permission below at the runtime? Location permission is a dangerous permission and needs to be granted by the user.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In addition, you don't have to create a fragment class and implement the `IOnMapReadyCallback` interface. According to this case about [using GoogleMaps Api in the native android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68500195/17455524), you can only make the activity which layout contains the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` implement the `IOnMapReadyCallback` interface.

For more details, you can refer to the offical sample code about [adding mark in the google maps](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/03a34d80a7b4118ad359b29309e5e8d1cd898202/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/SimpleMapDemo/MapWithMarkersActivity.cs#L13).